# Как сделать кроссразмерное активи

Tags: android, xml

К примеру есть:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/rootLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/colorWhite"
              tools:context="com.hideme.Menu" android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:onClick="startGame"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/empty"
            android:src="@drawable/button_start"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">
        <ImageButton
                android:onClick="startGame"
                android:background="@drawable/settings"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="20pt" android:layout_width="52dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Как сделать одно активи, чтобы на любом экране оно отображалось одинаково?

Изменил на:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/colorWhite"
              tools:context="com.hideme.Menu">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:onClick="startGame"
            android:background="@drawable/empty"
            android:src="@drawable/button_start"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Что значит одинаково?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Имеется в виду, что на всех устройствах расположение блоков будет на одном уровне, но разных размеров. К примеру на эмуляторе запускаю и на своём устройстве и на устройстве с меньшим разрешением экрана приложение съезжает и не все элементы на активити.

Comment: Вам нужен вес 1 для всех детей первого уровня корневого LinearLayout. Им же высоту поставьте 0dp

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а про какую высоту идёт речь?

Comment: `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал android:layout_height="0dp" и все элементы сдвинулись в верх. Код с изменениями выложил выше в вопросе.
[Картинка](http://joxi.ru/8An9lVPi5ZOM2O)

Comment: Замените android:weightSum на  android:weight. И вроде нельзя под вертикальным layout помещать вертикальные элементы. Нужно чередовать.

Comment: Заменил на layout_weight, но теперь два элемента ImageButton и LinearLayout стали занимать 50 на 50 процентов всей области, а мне необходимо, чтобы Layout занимал 30 процентов..

Comment: @J.Defenses значит установите для `ImageButton` свойство `android:weight` = 2. Или вообще попробуйте новый [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)